# What is the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm not sure how to translate the following sentence:

「お前（末永）ほどのアホは初めて見たが、お前のアホは俺様（小林）が観察する為にあるのだから、むやみに人前でアホを披露してはいけない」（『ゴーマニズム宣言』より）が採用理由の一つだと言う。

( taken from [https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/末永直海](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%AB%E6%B0%B8%E7%9B%B4%E6%B5%B7) )

This is how I translate it:

"This is the first time I've seen anybody as stupid as you. Because I'll be observing you, don't be reckless and show your stupidity in front of other people" (according to Gomanism sengen, this is one reason she (末永直海) was hired (by 小林))

I feel my translation doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the part お前のアホは俺様が観察する為にある, where you translate as "I'll be observing you."

The subject of this sub-sentence is お前のアホ "your stupidity," and the predicate (the verb) is ある "exists."

The rest of the sub-sentence 俺様が観察する[為]{ため}に modifies the verb ある.

V (dictionary form) + ために means "in order to V," so 俺様が観察する為に is "in order for me to observe."

So the literal translation of the whole sub-sentence is:

> Your stupidity exists in order for me to observe.

That might include the nuance of "I solely have the right to observe your stupidity," which naturally connects to the next part むやみに人前でアホを披露してはいけない.

---

Other part of your translation seems good. One thing, I would prefer "unnecessarily" or "excessively" for the word むやみに.